# How do i create triggers i have my code but it has an error

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace TRIGGER "CARAVAN"
    before insert or update ON caravan
        FOR EACH ROW DECLARE cara_no number;
            BEGIN
                if inserting then
                    if :new.caravan_no is null then
                       select caravan.nextval into cara_no from dual;   
                       :new.caravan := cara_no;
                    end if;
                    if :new.tags is not null then
                       :new.tags := caravan_new.tags_cleaner(:new.tags);
                    end if;
                end if;
                caravan_new.tag_sync(
                    p_new_tags => :new.tags,
                    p_old_tags => :old.tags,
                    p_content_type => 'CUSTOMER',
                    p_content_id => :new.caravan_no );
            END;
```

These are the two errors with my code

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error   



PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: 
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma 
  raise return select update while with <an identifier>
```

Comment: And this error is? Plus, at least take some time to format this properly. Right now it's basically unreadable junk.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: how would i change the code for it to be correct

Comment: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>

Comment: Im sorry i don't know how to use the site 100%

Comment: Unrelated, but: the sequence handling can be simplified to `:new.caravan := caravan.nextval`

Comment: Which tool do you use to run this statement? Is that the only statement you are running? Typically you need a `/` after a PL/SQL block to make it work.

Comment: through sql workshop but i still cant get it to work, it comes up with the same error message can someone change the code and make it correct